IF formula along with date - today networkdays formula
I need a formula that will not only calculate networkdays betwen a date and today, but I also want it to start with column L and calculate. If column L is blank, I need it to tell me how many days are between column M and today.I have tried =IF(L2=0,M2)-NETWORKDAYS[M2-today()] but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
